# How call a specific method from property aspect with property name and prefix?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I want to develop a NotifyDataErrorInfoAspect with possharp.

The validation of the values depends on several changeable properties (MinValue, MaxValue ...). The contract can't work with variable parameters.

I want to build something similar to the DependencyPropertyAspect.
Each property with [DependencyProperty] has a number of optional methods. For example ValidatePropertyName.

```
[DependencyProperty]
public string Email { get; set; }

private bool ValidateEmail(string value)
{
    return EmailRegex.IsMatch(value);
}
```

How can I do this?

```
[NotifyDataErrorInfo]
public string Name{ get; set; }
private IList<DataErrorInfo> ValidateName(string value)
{
    return this.IsValidName(value);
}

[NotifyDataErrorInfo]
public int Age{ get; set; }
private IList<DataErrorInfo> ValidateAge(int value)
{
    return this.IsValidAge(value);
}

[NotifyDataErrorInfo]
public string Email { get; set; }
private IList<DataErrorInfo> ValidateEmail(string value)
{
    return this.IsValidEmail(value);
}
```

The attribute ImportMethod () only allows a fixed method name.
What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to import a method that doesn't have a fixed predefined name, you can implement `IAdviceProvider` interface in your aspect and provide `ImportMethodAdviceInstance` that takes a method name as a string argument.

Another important point is that your Validate methods take arguments of a specific type instead of `object`. Currently, it's not possible to create a generic attribute in C#, so you need to create two aspect classes to handle this case: an attribute that is an aspect provider and a generic aspect implementation.

Below is a sample implementation of NotifyDataErrorInfo aspect:

```
[PSerializable]
public class NotifyDataErrorInfoAttribute : LocationLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type propertyType = ((LocationInfo)targetElement).LocationType;
        Type aspectType = typeof(NotifyDataErrorInfoAspectImpl<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType);

        yield return new AspectInstance(
            targetElement, (IAspect) Activator.CreateInstance(aspectType));
    }
}

[PSerializable]
public class NotifyDataErrorInfoAspectImpl<T> : ILocationInterceptionAspect,
                                                IInstanceScopedAspect,
                                                IAdviceProvider
{
    public Func<T, IList<DataErrorInfo>> ValidateDelegate;

    public IEnumerable<AdviceInstance> ProvideAdvices(object targetElement)
    {
        LocationInfo property = (LocationInfo)targetElement;
        string validateMethodName = "Validate" + property.Name;

        yield return new ImportMethodAdviceInstance(
            typeof(NotifyDataErrorInfoAspectImpl<>).GetField("ValidateDelegate"),
            validateMethodName,
            true);
    }

    public void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (ValidateDelegate((T) args.Value)?.Any() == true)
            throw new ArgumentException("...");

        args.ProceedSetValue();
    }

    public void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        args.ProceedGetValue();
    }

    public void RuntimeInitialize(LocationInfo locationInfo)
    {
    }

    public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!
I will put this into my project and test it. Some questions.

The implementation of the INotifyDataErrorInfo I have another aspect classe. I use NotifyPropertyChangeAspect. How should the two aspect work together? I would not like to copy NotifyPropertyChangeAspect in my classe, but also not have to specify second aspect. The code of NotifyPropertyChangeAspect is not known to me. Do you have eventuel some points that I have to pay attention.

Comment: I would like to analyze the validaion code to find dependencies to other properties. Dependent validations should be considered. "Max Value" changes should call the validation of the value.

Comment: 1) The NotifyDataErrorInfoAttribute.ProvideAspects method can also provide NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute on the type where the property is defined. You can use [IAspectRepositoryService](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-40-Aspect-Repository) to check whether the aspect has already been applied on the type. However, I think that in this case it's cleaner to specify the two aspects separately, as each provides a different behavior in your code. You would also want to order your aspect before the INPC (http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-dependencies).

Comment: 2) You can use GetMethodsUsingDeclaration method from PostSharp's [ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) class. So, in your example you would find all the set_Property methods where get_MaxValue is used. Then you can import the validation methods of those properties and invoke them at run-time.